# When I try to set email alert if my pipeline failure in Azure data factory: I couldn't select pipeline names in the list while configuring alert logic

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, oracle-adf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k85Vz.jpg)

Please guide the steps to create my email alert successful, Pipeline names itself not populating to select.

I tried to set email notifications when pipeline fails in adf ..Monitor tab : Alerts and metrics- New alert rule -configuring already logic